# In .htaccess files, is there any difference at all between “!=on” and “off”

Tags: htaccess, apache, https, mod-rewrite

I’m trying to better understand Apache’s use of a binary attribute. In an `.htaccess` file with the code

```
# Check if HTTPS is  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

Is there more processing occurring – *at any level* – than there is with the similar code

```
# Check if HTTPS is 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** In this example, the net result is the same, but the pattern `!=on` is arguably more efficient because it is a lexicographical string comparison, not a regular expression. Unlike `off`, which is processed as a regex.

However, in real terms, there is no measurable performance difference between these particular expressions. It's a matter of personal preference which one you choose. (You could also use `!on` instead.)

Note that the `HTTPS` server variable should always be set. It is set to either `off` or `on` (lowercase) exactly. The regex `off` checks that the value is set to "off" (or, strictly speaking *contains* "off"). However, the regex `!=on` (or `!on`) is successful whenever the value is not "on", so if the `HTTPS` server variable was not set at all (for whatever reason) or set to "something" else entirely then it would also be successful - which wouldn't necessarily be correct. However, as noted, the `HTTPS` server var *should* always be set and never be anything other than `on` or `off`. So in this instance, it should make no difference.

---

> Apache’s use of a binary attribute...

This isn't strictly a "binary attribute". All Apache *server variables* contain strings. In the case of the `HTTPS` server variable, this is set to either the string "on" or "off" (always lowercase).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
> ```

(Note this has a different meaning to `!on`.)

- The `!` prefix (which can be prefixed to *any* condition) negates the result of the condition.
- The important part here is the `=` operator. This changes the expression from being a regex comparison to a lexicographical string comparison for equality. The fact that it is no longer a regex is what arguably makes it "more efficient" (although in real terms, there is no measurable performance difference in this example). So, `=on` checks that the server variable `HTTPS` is exactly equal to "on". The `!` prefix then negates the result. Whereas `off` checks that `HTTPS` *contains* the string "off" anywhere (the same as `^.*off.*$`).

The comparable expression to `!=on` is really `=off`, not `off` (as in your example). And `off` is comparable to `!on`. The fact that you rarely see `=off` is just human nature, personal preference, habit, copy/paste, readability, misunderstanding (take your pick)?

**In summary:**

```
# Check if HTTPS is not exactly equal to "on" (lexicographical comparison)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

vs

```
# Check if HTTPS contains the string "off" anywhere (regex)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

Answer (score 0):

### Not Equal to & Not

A short answer - No they are the same. `!=` is an [operator](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Companion/cxx_crib/equality.html) that means not equal to. Therefore `!=on` and `off` mean the same in the `.htaccess` code.

In English, the two examples you provided mean:

> If not equal to https
>
> or
>
> If https is off

They are just different ways of writing the same thing.

---

### Related:

[What is the origin of != in the meaning “not equal to”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22336/what-is-the-origin-of-in-the-meaning-not-equal-to)

Comment: "`!=` is an operator" - in Apache speak, `!=` isn't strictly the operator. The operator is simply `=`, with a `!` prefix. The negation prefix (`!`) can be applied to _any_ condition in order to _negate the result_: `!on`, `!<foo`, `!-f`, etc.